# SQLite database maximum storage capacity

Tags: android, database, sqlite

How many records in an SQLite database can we maximally store? Is there any limitation? If the data goes beyond this limitation what type of error does it give? Will the whole the system fail, or what else happens?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3482635/what-is-a-maximum-size-of-sqlite-database-on-android

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Based on [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db) page:

> Android does not impose any limitations beyond the standard SQLite
>   concepts. We do recommend including an autoincrement value key field
>   that can be used as a unique ID to quickly find a record. This is not
>   required for private data, but if you implement a content provider,
>   you must include a unique ID using the BaseColumns._ID constant.

The limit is tied to [SQLite limitation](http://www.sqlite.org/limits.html). As for what happened when we hit that limit, I guess android will raise [SQLiteFullException](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteFullException.html).

Comment: Thanks @silent, If i store 1 0r 2 days Location information on sqlite for peridiocity of 15 minutes , will it become full? How can i truncate the table  if database become full?

Comment: 4*24 = 96 entry / day = 1.000.000.000 / 96 = ~28500 years. I think, for your situation, you will never have to truncate. However, you can still do `DELETE * FROM yourtable`, to truncate it's data.

Answer (score 4):

Its 140 terabytes Maximum . **In more details**

> SQLite was originally designed with a policy of avoiding arbitrary
>   limits. Of course, every program that runs on a machine with finite
>   memory and disk space has limits of some kind. But in SQLite, those
>   limits were not well defined. The policy was that if it would fit in
>   memory and you could count it with a 32-bit integer, then it should
>   work.