# Storage limitations for WebSQL on iOS (with PhoneGap)

Tags: ios, sqlite, cordova, web-sql

I am currently using Local Storage on both Android and iOS, but reaching capacity limits. So I thought to switch to WebSQL, which is of course deprecated but still working on both platforms.

The question is: is there any limitation regarding the maximum size of the database beside of the natural limitations of Sqlite databases?

I know the answer for Android, which is 'no' (see [SQLite database maximum storage capacity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8502070/sqlite-database-maximum-storage-capacity)).

But it would be nice to get it for iOS, too, before implementing.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [FT lab](http://labs.ft.com/2012/06/text-re-encoding-for-optimising-storage-capacity-in-the-browser/), 50 MB is the limit for iOS.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post but during my testing on WebSQL on iOS I also found that the limit was around 50MB.

I created a plugin to work around this limit for storage.

https://github.com/Thinkwise/cordova-plugin-update-quota