# osmdroid sqlite tile source

Tags: android, sqlite, mapping, offline, osmdroid

I want to add a SQLite tile provider to OSMDroid just like RMaps. I went through OSMDroid source code and its tile providers and I found that they are designed to get tiles from File, Archive file and internet.

I am using osmdroid-android 3.0.5.

Comment: Why do you need a DB?  Have you seen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3482635/what-is-a-maximum-size-of-sqlite-database-on-android

Comment: I want to add some meta data to my Maps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't belive this is possible with the current Osmdroid library.  If you want to do it you will have to create your own TileProvider to fit into the framework which should be possible.

I expect that using an archive file for the actual map tiles and a seperate database for your meta data is by far the simplest solution.  Putting large amounts of data like the tiles into the database is not recomended.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this](https://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=3154177&group_id=238075&atid=1105496) page. I think this is what you are looking for :o)

*I recently implemented a sqlite storage for the tiles of the osmdroid lib, and the only thing missing is the ability to create it with mobac. So I wrote this patch to provide the new output option. Please have a look and commit it if you like it. Let me know if you think I should change something.*

Comment: would you please get more details? What should I do to get job done?

Comment: Check out this [page]  (http://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/wiki/MobileAtlasCreator)   

There you you can see some info regarding making sqlite archives to use with osmdroid using the **Mobile Atlas Creator** _desktop_ application.   

Also there is a **newer version of osmdroid-android** (3.0.8) which can be downloaded [here](http://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/downloads/list)

Comment: osmdroid-android-3.0.8 has an issue. After some zooming in and out, tiles will disappear.

Comment: i do not have those issues... And what about 3.0.7

Comment: I read somewhere that this is an issue and proposed to back to 3.0.5. I changed the jar and everything was ok. I didn't try other versions.

Comment: Sorry! I didn't understand what you said! You sent me a patch for MOBAC but I need modified source (or jar) of osmdroid to accept sqlite as tile source.