# Which is more heavier sqlite file? single or split file?

Tags: android, sqlite

I am developing an android app that uses sqlite and I want to reduce the size of my database (for now it is 500Mb), will splitting the file into 100 parts decrease or increase the size of my database?

Comment: certainly not decrease if the underlying volume of data is the same, and probably increase slightly because you'll need a little metadata for each file.  Performance will also decrease for operations that need to scan all separate databases, but there might be a big performance boost for operations that can query only one of the separate databases.  Make sure all your sql data really needs to be in the database

Comment: @JunaidKhalid that is a pretty pointless suggestion if that's not the goal of the app :)

Comment: @a_local_nobody It is not useless, in fact I have thought of splitting the database because I need to work with only one at a time, so the speed of the query increases

Comment: If you want to reduce it's size, better try structuring it better. What's the problem? https://stackoverflow.com/a/28243038/11880323

Comment: you completely misunderstood what i said, in fact i made no reference to your question at all, as you can see i was replying to someone completely different - `@JunaidKhalid`