# Android APP with a local database

Tags: android, mysql

If building an app for android tablet, how big can the local database be ?

Do you this it could handle a database of 5 million registries (Read Only) ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a maximum size of SQLite database on Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3482635/what-is-a-maximum-size-of-sqlite-database-on-android)

Comment: The size of your database doesn't depend on the number of your entries only, it depends on what you put in which entry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like Distwo describes, the size in a `Sqlite` Database depends on what you put into the database not in the number of entries.

Check this document about `Sqlite` limits **http://www.sqlite.org/limits.html**