# How much data can be stored on a sql lite db on a mobile device (ios/android)

Tags: android, sqlite, cordova, ionic-framework

I am making a cross-platform app which requires me to call web services and then store that data into a sql lite database on the users device.

I have a lot of data(text) from the webservice that I need to store in a local db, so that the app can work offline. I was wondering how much data it is possible to store. Also has anyone got any tips on challenges I could experience in doing such a thing.

I see the original that you have posted is very old. Android has changed a lot since 2010.

Thanks

Comment: i think it is depends upon mobile memory

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3482635/what-is-a-maximum-size-of-sqlite-database-on-android

Answer (score 1):

I think you don't need to care about maximum size, because it can be up to 140 terabytes.
http://www.sqlite.org/limits.html

Actually, you will be limited by size of the storage of the phone.