# Does android support large database tables

Tags: android, database

I am working on project that require storing large data in tables in smartphone within the application. I already searched through google about this topic but did not find anything. so I need to know if android smartphone support database of 700 MB and how the response time would be to retrieve the data.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a maximum size of SQLite database on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3482635/what-is-a-maximum-size-of-sqlite-database-on-android)

Comment: @second this question is very old and does not reflect the change that has been done on smartphone market

Comment: While the question is quite old, the mentioned limits are still accurate. But the `SQLite` limitations are not directly concerned with hardware limitations. I consider it likely that you hit those first (in a smartphone). Response Time is dependant on the data you store, on the hardware you use and whatever else is currently running on the phone. I doubt you find an explicit answer for that.

Comment: I know that but I ask to see if someone work with data of this size on smartphone and know about the performance or if they use partitioning to improve the performance

Answer (score 0):

Android contains an SQLite DBMS within itself. You can create and manipulate databases within your android application with SQLite. You can find tutorials for creating and manipulating SQLite android databases: [here](https://www.google.com/search?ei=L8FiXdT8KIrewAKIk5yADg&q=android%20sqlite%20tutorials&oq=android%20sqlite%20tutorials&gs_l=psy-ab.3.%20.0i19l2j0i22i30i19l8.3977.75976..76398%200.1..0.901.4993.1j20j0j1j2j0j1%20...%20......%200%20....%201..gws-wiz%20.....%200..0i71j0i67j0i131i67j0i131j0j0i22i30.o13OapY3OKw%20&%20ved%20=%200ahUKEwiU0KaCwp7kAhUKL1AKHYgJB-AQ4dUDCAo%20&%20UACT%20=%205)
They represent internal dadabases in the phone like the contacts manager application that we find in each phone.

Otherwise you can put your database in a remote server and you can manage it  using RESTful web services : [here](https://www.google.com/search?ei=fcFiXbXlMtDSwAKEjI24Bw&q=android%20mysql%20php%20json%20tutorial&oq=android%20mysql%20php&gs_l=psy-ab.1.1.0j0i22i30l9.191723.199603..201535...0.2..1.748.2690.0j7j2j0j1j0j1......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71j0i67j0i131.m3g5kfZLA2E)

Comment: I know how to create a database in android but I am wondering about the capacity of the database in smartphone